# How to wait for ParseQuery to complete (findInBackground)?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I posted an unanswered question asking why this ParseQuery would return an empty list instead of a list of users. After looking from the logcat, I believe it to be an issue with the execution continuing before the ParseQuery has filled the list.

```
public List<ParseUser> getDataset() {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("foo", true).findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // your logic here
                for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                    mDataset.add(user);
                    Log.d("data", mDataset.toString());
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                // handle Parse Exception here
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    Log.d("final", mDataset.toString());
    return mDataset;
}
```

The logcat shows an empty list first, then a new line for each list with a new item added- indicating the that (empty) list is returned before the query is complete.

Question: Is there a way to wait for the query to complete before carrying out the return?

Comment: no. doing network calls on the main thread is not aloud. the way you are doing it now it the correct way to be doing it. init the list with an empty array and add in the data in the listener once it comes back from the backend

Comment: Could you elaborate on your last sentence please? Isn't that what I'm currently doing already?

Comment: yes. thats what you are doing now, and thats how it should be done

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm afraid that doesn't answer how to wait for the query to complete before executing the return statement. Any ideas?

Comment: you cant. thats what im saying. there is no way to do that

Comment: whats the problem right now. if you tell me why you think you need to do that im sure we can come up with a correct way of doing it

Comment: I appreciate the help. The problem is the data retrieved from the backend that is to fill the list is retrieved in the background, allowing for the rest of the program to be executed. Because of this, the list is returned empty as the return statement is executed before the completion of the network call.

Comment: but i can see you do mDataset.add(user);  and then mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  so after it returns from the backend it should update your list and show the users.

Comment: It must be something to do with my adapter as notifyDataSetChanged() appears to do nothing (i.e. same logcat without that line). I'll look into this.

Comment: I've changed `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to `mAdapter.updateList(mDataset)` where `updateList` clears the list and adds the new list then calls `this.notifyDataSetChanged()` -- the outcome is still the same, however the logcat reveals that the new list IS passed to the adapter.

Comment: Turns out my code worked. For some reason my `TextView` layout_width in my recycler_row_item.xml was set to 0dp - thus not displaying anything. Resolved!

Comment: For anyone else that stumbles onto this like I did, there are ways to wait for the query. @TomerShemesh is only reciting the SOP for async procedures, but if you have another background task that relies on the first, this won't be enough. You can set a boolean for task completion and use a while statement to check it before launching the next one.